# how to join two select in one? SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I need to display the departure and arrival airport codes with their names from another table. But I don't know how to do this in one request

```
select flight_no, a.departure_airport, b.airport_name from flights a
join airports_data b on a.departure_airport = b.airport_code
```

```
select flight_no, a.arrival_airport, b.airport_name from flights a
join airports_data b on a.arrival_airport = b.airport_code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tableairport_data twince

```
select flight_no, a.arrival_airport, b.airport_name as arrival_airport_name , a.departure_airport, b.airport_name as departure_airport_name from flights a
join airports_data b on a.departure_airport = b.airport_code
Join airports_data c on a.arrival_airport = c.airport_code
```

Comment: No(
In this case, the columns are duplicated by the first "join"

Comment: like:PG0216 KUF {"en": "Domodedovo International Airport", "ru": "Домодедово"} DME {"en": "Domodedovo International Airport", "ru": "Домодедово"}

Comment: then post your table with data, you didn't mention that you use json and please edit your question

Answer (score 0):

You can join `airports_data` as `b` and `c` and then use the fields of `a`, `b` and `c`, you can also rename `airport_name` inside your `select` clause to differentiate between `b` and `c`

```
select flight_no, a.departure_airport, a.arrival_airport, b.airport_name b_name, c.airport_name as c_name from flights a
join airports_data b on a.departure_airport = b.airport_code
join airports_data c on a.arrival_airport = c.airport_code
```

Comment: Happy to help. You might accept this answer if it solved the problem.

Comment: that the same like mine